# Multiple http request in the background using angular 6

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I have to fetch data on small batches to complete the data I already have in the frontend,
So let say I have hundreds of objects of an id, name and the other fields are empty as I have to get them from another endpoint on by passing the id, however, this other endpoint is quite slow and I need to do this process for let say 5 at the time and in the background "without interrupting any other requests".

What is the best approach to do that? and append the fetched data to its corresponding item inside the list of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you start with an array of objects of which you know `id` and `name`. You need to populate all these objects with additional data which you can fetch using a slow API, and therefore you do not want to have more than 5 of such requests flying at a time.

Let's assume that the invocation of such API is implemented via the method `getDataForId(id)` and that the populate of the object with the additional data retrieved from the API is performed by the method `populate(obj, data)` where `obj` is the object that has to be populated and `data` is the raw data to be used to populate the object.

If this is all right, you can consider an approach along these lines

```
const objArray = [
  {id: 123, name: 'first'},
  {id: 456, name: 'second'},
  ......
  {id: xyz, name: 'last'},
];

    from(objArray).pipe(
       mergeMap(
          obj => getDataForId(objArray.id).pipe(
             map(data => populate(obj, data))
          ), 5
       )
    )
    .subscribe()
```

**ALTERNATIVE IMPLEMENTATION - after the comment**

You can consider also to fetch the list from the back end and then get the items in chunks of 5 with full details. You can achieve this with code which would look like

```
getListOfIds().pipe(
   bufferCount(5),
   map(arrayOf5Ids => getDataForId(objArray.id).pipe(
             map(data => populate(obj, data))
   )),
   switchMap(arrayOf5Observables => forkJoin(arrayOfObservables)),
)
.subscribe(arrayOf5Items => // do what you want}
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly my situation. However, as I was investigating this I had another idea. How about in the first call which I get the whole list of objects I do the call to the slow API and return 5 items at the time that has the complete data instead of the long incomplete list? Do you think this is possible and better than showing a list of not complete data waiting for it to populate?

Comment: It is feasible to get first the list and then 5 items at a time with full details. See my updated answer. If this is better, I do not have any idea. I think it depends on the requirement you want to implement.

Comment: Thank you for the update, I don't understand it yet, I'll give it a go ASAP. In the main time, doesn't it solves the problem I posted in here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52436049/one-call-main-multiple-responses-in-asp-net-mvc-angular-6 ?

Comment: I had to back to this today as the other approach caused some problems. I just can't figure out how to filter or have some logic in this? because I don't need to get data from the slow API for everyone let say based on the name?

Comment: you can use `filter` like `getListOfIds().pipe(filter(obj => // your filter logic), bufferCount(5), .....)`

Comment: I'm using your first mergeMap solution. I was able to have a filter under the first pipe like filter(obj => obj.name== '')
now if the object does have a name I want to send it to populate without the need to go through the slow api?
Also, how can I execute something once from() is finished!

Comment: Okay I found it
complete: () => inside the subscribe
and I have changed obj => to a block just add it if/else and returned EMPTY on the else as I just passed the object to populate()

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 1):

you can use `mergeMap` , like this

```
  this.http.get('/api1').pipe(
      mergeMap(character => this.http.get('/api2'))
    ).subscribe(() => {
       ....  
    });
```

---

*References*
 - [Angular Multiple HTTP Requests with RxJS](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs)