# One call main, multiple responses in ASP.NET MVC + angular 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, rxjs, ienumerable

First of all, I have no idea if this is possible! and I'm struggling to find an answer. I think I don't know what to search for!

I have an endpoint that returns `IEnumerable`, I want to divide the response so I used

```
.Skip().Take()
```

Now when I get the first take, how can I get the second one without invoking the same endpoint!

The problem is `IEnumerable` gets the data from another service where it is not possible to divide, so I have to get everything at once and then I have to call another "SLOW" endpoint that gives me 5 results at the time using what I got from the `IEnumerable`.

So what I want to do is, divide the first list, do the second call, put the result together, return this and repeat until the list is completed.

Is there a way to keep angular listening for responses and append them as they arrive?

Or can I make another call after I get the result but without requesting the complete list again ? "save it somewhere!".

Comment: what kind of connection is this? socket or http?

Comment: http using rxjs observable/subscribe

I have set the IEnumerable to be static which is working but not sure if this is right!

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to what I was trying to achieve is **NO it is not possible**. The change has to be done on a deeper level (querying the DB).

Using static works but then this is a web application so that would be problematic so again its a NO.

I ended up getting the whole list, then looping through it one by one to get the slow data then show it to the user.